# Django Rest Framwork Issue

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, twitter, django-rest-framework

Hi guys I'm  trying to save many to many data from rest Post method when I post it give me blank none items added to many to many fields.

Please check and help me how I can fix this issue

Views.py

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def AddDisco(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data=request.data
        serializer = serializers.DiscoSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print('it is valid')
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        qs = Disco.objects.all()
        serailzer = serializers.DiscoSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response(serailzer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Models.py

```
class MusicGenre(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Disco(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(MusicGenre, blank=True)
```

Serializer.py

```
class DiscoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Disco
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

when I try to post from api it wont add the items in genre it gives me blank

Please help me to solve this issue

[image: please check this image]

Comment: you need to override the `create` method in `DiscoSerializer` and handle m2m fields yourself.

Comment: Thank you sajad for you help I need some additional Can you send me snipet code 
How I can do that ? it would be very helpful

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39406265/6906346). Notice that you have to create an object first, and then add m2m's to it.